# Activerecord or sinatra-activerecord for sinatra

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I am working first time on sinatra and faced with a choice of using activerecord or sinatra-activerecord gem. Couldn't find proper difference between the two. Can someone help me out.

Comment: > sinatra-activerecord: Extends Sinatra with extension methods and Rake tasks for dealing with an SQL database using the ActiveRecord ORM.

Comment: I used sinatra-activerecord and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Sirl33tname Perhaps you should add that as an actual answer, and maybe mention a few of the extension methods and rake tasks.  Then the OP can give it a check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just read the description it's quite clear which one you should use:

**activerecord**

> Databases on Rails. Build a persistent domain model by mapping database tables to Ruby classes. Strong conventions for associations, validations, aggregations, migrations, and testing come baked-in.

https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord/

**sinatra-activerecord**

> Extends Sinatra with ActiveRecord helpers.

https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-activerecord

So I guess for 99.5% of all cases just go with `sinatra-activerecord`.